# Unable to resolve resources using separate files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I feel like this is a common sense and trivial, but i don't understand what i'm doing to begin with.  I don't have any other resource I can use for help either.  Sometimes i wonder if I'm even googling the question right.

I have some custom styles & templates I've made, but now the file is rather large and difficult to work with.  I want to put each style or template in there own XAML files (sorta like headers/implementation files) so that a friend could work on one and then we add it to the project.  (Such as Dictionary1.xaml ... ).  I started a blank project to keep it simple.

**Dictionary1.XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary x:Key="SomeKey">
    <Color x:Key="detailMark">Black</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="detailMarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMark}" />
    <Style x:Key="flatTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.XAML**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MainWindow x:Key="SomeKey"/>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

**And MainWindow.XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" Width="525">


    <Grid>
        <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource flatTextBox}"> <!-- doesn't autocomplete/work -->

        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit:**

```
<TextBox Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource SomeKey}}">
        <!-- Throws System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException  -->

    </TextBox>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about that... I love this site, i just don't use it often.

Comment: Some google for you: try ["Merged Resource Dictionaries"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to organize your resource dictionaries in more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573395/alex) mentioned, the right way to do this is using [Merged Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Therefore, you should structure your project correctly, otherwise it will end up in a mess.

Keeping your "blank project", it should look like this:

- YourProject

  - App.xaml *(.cs)*
  - MainWindow.xaml *(.cs)*
  - SomeOtherWindow.xaml *(.cs)*
  - **Resources folder**

    - Dictionary1.xaml
    - Dictionary2.xaml
    - ...

Then you have to decide:

1. Do you want the resources to be available application wide?
2. Or do you want the resources to vary between certain windows / user controls?

---

If you want #1, you have to merge the dictionaries in the *App.xaml* file:

```
<Application x:Class=...
             ...>
    <Application.Resources>        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Dictionary2.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

If you want #2, you have to merge the dictionaries in the specific window / user control file:

```
<Window x:Class=...
        ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- Window specific resources -->
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- Content -->
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, for whatever reason, i ended up trying this and it worked perfectly.  I think it was a case of knowing is half the battle and I needed to know that Merged Dictionaries existed, and how to implement them.  After that, i created a blank project and used the example that alex mentioned and it worked.  I went back to my project and it worked as well.

I was getting so frustrated.